# how to read .dat files in c++

Tags: c++, sql-server

How to write code in C++ read .dat files, these files contain text data (numbers and characters organized with delimiters |). is fstream standard library the best choice? how can we define the file path. The second question is, if I want to read these files and load them into SQL server database, will it be different mechanism ??

Comment: Your question provides insufficient details to be answered: there is no “.dat file format”, `.dat` is a generic file extension. There is no “fstream library” – you probably mean the standard library class `std::fstream` but that question is a tautology: yes, you use it, but that won’t help you. Finally, you give no information about the data you’re dealing with so we cannot know how to load them into SQL server.

Comment: @KonradRudolph files contains texts, and written in a way that when I load them into database each file will form a table, they contains | as delimiters to separate columns, I could manually change the extension into txt and open and read them, I need to know how to write C++ code to read them

Comment: @jcarlos I haven't dealt with files before, so if you recommend some brief tutorial I'd be grateful

Comment: If your files are delimited and the data is clean, you could just use bcp.exe, BULK INSERT or even SSIS rather than write your own code. There are many questions on this site about importing csv or other delimited files into SQL Server.

Comment: @Pondlife I know about BULK INSERT but I need to do that in C++ as I'm trying to develop parallel algorithm of reading and loading, which is not applicable in BULK INSERT and SSIS. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use fstream for this.

Here is some code you could use
for splitting the data into an array devided by a delimiter. just change the 
DELIMITER to your delimiter.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include <cstring>

const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20;
const char* const DELIMITER = " ";

int main()
{
  // create a file-reading object
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("data.txt"); // open a file
  if (!fin.good()) 
    return 1; // exit if file not found

  // read each line of the file
  while (!fin.eof())
  {
    // read an entire line into memory
    char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
    fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

    // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
    int n = 0; // a for-loop index

    // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
    const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

    // parse the line
    token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
    if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
    {
      for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
      {
    token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
        if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
  }
}

    // process (print) the tokens
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
      cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

To store the data into a database take a look at [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could google it for yourself..but : Just do some tutorials.
for example : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
instead of .txt you just open .dat ( Since you say it contains only text data..)

for storing in a SQL database, i assume it will be MySQL now : 
http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/

For the steps: Open your file, open a database connection, do a INSERT INTO ....
done.